# c++ communicate with specific client Boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm new to c++ and I started to code my server with boost. I follow a lot of example on the web and on the official doc. But i found nothing (maybe I don't ask the good question) about this-> communicate with a specific client. By this I mean that->

**old question:**

> Server launch and wait for connection-> client(1) connect through
>   TCP-> server accept client and start async_read
>
> Let's say 3 clients also connect->
>
> How I'll tell to my server too write too client(2) or (3) but not
>   both?

*I express myself badly*

**New question:**

My server work fine, when client send data to server (custom client in Unreal engine 4) he can read it then write back to my client with no problem. I search a way to speak to the client I want without needed him to send data. Example:

client 1 write to server-> the data send to server launch the next action-> write to a specific client.

More specific example:

Client 1 want to send request to client 10, so client 1 write to the server the action «action, id client» (request, 10) then the server know that he need to talk to the client 10 and send request.

My problem is not on the client side, but on the server side.

I'm sure it's pretty easy and I just don't understand some basic stuff, if someone could provide me a direction, an example or simply an explanation it would be appreciated. Thanks for future answer.

EDIT:

If somebody have hard time like me (I know it's easy but we never know :p, maybe it could help someone) here the answer.

I include this inside the file where I use to connect, write, send, etc.

```
std::map<int, tcp::socket> playerRemote;
```

I set it->

```
playerRemote.insert(std::pair<int, tcp::socket>(id, std::move(socket_)));
```

use the socket->

```
boost::asio::async_read(playerRemote.at(id_to_use)
```

Question resolve! thanks for help!

Comment: Dude... examples about this are EVERYWHERE! Look here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html

Comment: What is the problem? If you have three sockets accepted, stored and are waiting to receive data via `async_read` then you can just call `write` or `async_write` on the socket connected to a particular client.

Comment: If you want to send data to specific clients, you could store them in, for example, a `std::map` along with the IPv4/6 address or a name [...] and send the data... as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks for reply everybody.

 @TheQuantumPhysicist As I say I'm new with c++ and boost, I just search more specific information about my question, also my level of english is also pretty low, so I may not understand how the process.

yurikilochek and Blacktempel Thanks for cue, I'll search for std::map in example.

Comment: @Blacktempel I created a std::map variable to old the endpoint like this->

std::map<int, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint> playerRemote;

and it work great, in the int I store the id of each user when they connect to the server, now I just need to find the way to write to the specific endpoint, I'll probably try do this all the day (I'm noob I know) if you have advice tell me. Also if I find the solution I'll mark the question as solved :)

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist if you want to read my new question and tell me if it make more sense now, sorry if it still something obvious, I just don't get it.

Comment: You can't write to an endpoint. In ASIO that's a network address. You use endpoints to connect sockets. Then you use the socket to read and write.

Comment: I think ZMQ for communication with Google Protocol Buffers for data serialization is a better fit for you than Boost ASIO. You can in ZMQ easily use a publish/subscribe comm model to send information to a specific end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time that your server program did an `accept` it got a new socket with a new client on the other end of it.

The usual practice is to have some kind of object which you create and initialize with this new socket. And then you put that object into some kind of structure. Like a set, a map, a vector, a list, *anything* really.

When you want a particular client then search that data structure for it. If you used a map or a unordered_map then you can get it quickly by whatever key you used.

Now you have your client object you can call a method on it. Like your own version of "send" which can add it to a per-client buffer. Since message sending is asynchronous in Boost ASIO (it's right there in the name) you know you may not be able to send it right away.

The Boost ASIO chat example application is good about this.

Look at the link that The Quantum Physicist put in comments. Especially this one: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_server.cpp

Comment: thanks for your answer! I already try to put the socket inside a map, but it give me an error. I'll edit my question to let you know how I do it and what the error, thanks again!

Comment: I finally get it! I edit my post with the answer even if it's an easy task, maybe someone will use it. If you have some precision about how I done it, I'm open to all suggestion! thanks everybody for sharing your answer!